# How to check if user doesn't write numbers or for example punctuation marks in edittext when he had to write his name

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have layout when user have to write name and surname. How can I check if he truly wrote name an surname and doesn't write numbers or other marks instead of it. Please, help!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify inputType of your EditText.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:inputType

Also you can add TextWatcher to your EditText and check user input
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

Answer (score 0):

Try this

It wont allow any special character or numeric value in **EditText**

```
 android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```